# LINQ Equivalent MYSQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I generate a report using the following query in an old classic asp application using MySQL database.  I now want to convert this to an MVC4 application. I need help badly  to have its equivalent with linq.   The query works as its by any help will be appreciated.

```
      SELECT report_date.rep_year, report_date.rep_month, bob.salecnt, bob.Tsales, cob.Tgift, cob.TGiftSum, dob.Ttgift, dob.TtGiftSum 
FROM report_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(x.s_date) AS rep_year, Month(x.s_date) AS rep_month, sum(x.bk_qty) as salecnt, sum(x.bk_qty*x.s_price) as Tsales 
    FROM sale x 
    WHERE x.s_date <= curdate() 
    and x.s_date >'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month
)as bob
ON bob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND bob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(y.gDate) AS rep_year, Month(y.gDate) AS rep_month, sum(y.gQty) as Tgift, sum(y.gQty*y.gPrice)as TGiftSum 
    From  gift y 
    WHERE  y.gbktype =1 
    and y.gdate <= curdate() 
    and y.gdate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month
)as cob
ON cob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND cob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(z.gdate) AS rep_year, Month(z.gdate) AS rep_month, sum(z.gQty) as Ttgift, sum(z.gQty*z.gprice)as TtGiftSum 
    From  gift z 
    WHERE z.gbktype =2 
    and z.gdate <= curdate() 
    and z.gDate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month 
)as dob 
ON dob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND dob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
WHERE CONCAT(report_date.rep_year, report_date.rep_month) > '201010'
AND CONCAT(report_date.rep_year, report_date.rep_month) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m')
```

This query links  the following tables

```
report_date [rep_id, rep_month, rep_year]
sale[sale_id,book_id,book_qty,s_date,s_price]
gift[gift_id,book_id,gQty,gDate,gPrice,gbooktype]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the specific problem you are encountering while trying to do this yourself? Please be more specific in your question rather than just asking S.O. to do the work for you.

Comment: LOL. *Please convert my 250-line SQL query to LINQ*. Yes, I'm willing to do that. [**For Profit**](http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzbbj4Rk7Z1qecnm7o1_500.jpg).

Comment: It is getting exciting but I will get there in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

LINQ Select Example:

```
IEnumerable<int> squares =
                Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);

            foreach (int num in squares)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             1
             4
             9
             16
             25
             36
             49
             64
             81
             100
            */
```

LINQ Join Example:

```
var innerGroupJoinQuery2 =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
    from prod2 in prodGroup
    where prod2.UnitPrice > 2.50M
    select prod2;
```

MSDN links for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines at least now I have an idea how to approach the problem